# When autowiring does a copy of the instance get returned?

Tags: spring

If I have a bean definition with some configuration within it and I use autowire to get an instance of the same class, is it the instance of the bean definition I get returned or a new instance of the class without any configurations?

```
class Name {
 private fName;
 private lName;
 constructor(string fName, string lName) {
  this.fName = fName;
  this.lName = lName;
 }
}


@Bean
public Name getName() {
 Name test = new Name(thisIsMyFirstName, thisIsMyLastName);
}


--Separate File--
@Autowired
private Name testName;
```

Is testName here a copy of the @Bean getName() (has thisIsMyFirstName and thisIsMyLastName set) or is it a new instance of the class Name without a first name of thisIsMyFirstName and last name of thisIsMyLastName?

Answer (score 2):

By default, yes, beans are singletons.
But, the Spring framework defines a number of different scopes.

**singleton**
Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.

**prototype**
Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.

**request**
Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is each and every HTTP request will have its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

**session**
Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

**global session**
Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

The scope of a bean can be change using the @Scope annotation.

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton") // <- singleton is the default. If no @Scope annotation is present, this is what is used.
public BeanA sharedBean() {

    // This will only be called once, all subsequent calls will return from the cached reference in the ApplicationContext
    return new BeanA();
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public BeanB privateBean() {

    // This will be called every time the bean is injected and a new instance returned.
    return new BeanB();
}
```

This is just another syntax
`@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)`

Comment: Okay, just to make sure, I do get the same instance of the bean with the configurations I set in my example rather than a new one without any, correct? If so, this is how Java Spring is able to spread the same instance of an object all around the project where needed...

Comment: Correct, your bean has the default scope of singleton. There is a single instance across the spring container.